# output the names/ids list of node for subgraph (subisomorphisms)

Tags: r, igraph, subgraph, isomorphism

I would like to count the number of the full 3-node subgraphs.
Nodes of the original graph have names. The example code is below.

```
g <- graph.full(n=5, directed = TRUE)

# adjacency matrices 
d3<-matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)

# Turn them into a convenient list
sbgDouble.mat<-list(d3)

# And then into a list of graph objects
sbgDouble.graph<-lapply(sbgDouble.mat, graph.adjacency)

# Count the number of the full 3-node subgraph

subgraph.freq.g<-c()

subgraph.freq.g[1]<-
graph.count.subisomorphisms.vf2(g, sbgDouble.graph[[1]])

#> subgraph.freq.g
# [1]  60
```

**Update:** I have tried `graph.get.isomorphisms.vf2(g, sbgDouble.graph[[1]])` but result is `list()`.

Could some one please say me how to output the names/ids list of nodes for 3-node subgraph? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to see vertex IDs we can use the function `graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2()`, for example,

```
graph.get.subisomorphisms.vf2(g, sbgDouble.graph[[1]])[1]
[[1]]
+ 3/5 vertices:
[1] 1 2 3
```